# jquery delegate does not seem to be working using combobox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

to I have tried trigger certain events based on the value change of a combobox using delegate.
But it seems that delegate is not being invoked at all.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gYPuE/)

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
       (function( $ ) {
          $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $('.ui-widget').delegate('#combobox','change',function(){
      alert("delegate triggered");
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: man buy yourself a brain in order, you request jquery 1.9 you use delegate that he's deprecated then you state you use 1.4; you don't make any sense

Comment: I could not paste all of my code here.. and thought would use the sample code on the jquery website...but totally forgot that it uses the latest version.

Comment: @mikakun have a little respect. Not all organizations are at liberty to upgrade just because the latest and greatest is out. Insults don't help anything here. `delegate` is avalable in 1.4.3 also and was implemented to get rid of `live()`

Answer (score 1):

WHen using a widget in jQUery UI they all provide numerous events you can bind to and it is best to work within that API and not try to work with events that may not trigger on the original element.

In this case use `select` event which you can use in the options config and also triggers   `autocompleteselect`

```
 $( "#combobox" ).combobox()
 $('.ui-widget').bind("autocompleteselect",function(){
  alert("delegate triggered");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gYPuE/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hey.. thanks man... but as I've said I use old version of Jquery. Also, the "_on" from the widget factory does not seem to be available in my case.I have updated the code to include the correct files here. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/gYPuE/5/)

Comment: can replace `on` with `delegate`. Using `delegate` was not your problen, it was `change` event which is why always best to use the widget methods and events

Comment: I have tried it.. that would not work.. I guess the "_on" is different from the "on" you are talking about. "on" can replaced with "delegate" but in the code sample that you sent we cannot replace "this._on" with something like "this.delegate" or "this._delegate". The methods that can be used are **[here](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/)**

Comment: yes likely is...that plugin was written long time ago also. Go to demo and says is not official plugin and info takes you to learningjquery.com article about 4 years ago

Comment: I think I just figured it out.. you may have to change **"this._on"** to **"this.element.delegate"** which is basically the **underlying select**.